# How to create sybase external table for SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

I am trying to create an external table using SQL server 2019 to sybase.
I am already able to create a linked server to sybase using the same driver and login information.

I am able to exec this code *with no error*:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE external_data_source_name
WITH ( 
LOCATION = 'odbc://jjjjj.nnnn.iiii.com:xxxxx',
CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'DRIVER={SQL Anywhere 17};
ServerNode = jjjjj.nnnn.iiii.com:xxxxx;
Database = report;
Port = xxxxx',
CREDENTIAL = [PolyFriend] );
```

but when I try to create a table using the data source

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE v_data(
event_id int 
) WITH (
LOCATION='report.dbo.v_data',
DATA_SOURCE=external_data_source_name
);
```

I get this error:

> 105082;Generic ODBC error: [SAP][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Database
>   server not found.

Comment: Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere or Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise?

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the Host & ServerName & DatabaseName properties (for SQL Anywhere) in the connection_options

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE external_data_source_name
WITH ( 
LOCATION = 'odbc://jjjjj.nnnn.iiii.com:xxxxx',
CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'DRIVER={SQL Anywhere 17};
Host=jjjjj.nnnn.iiii.com:xxxxx; 
ServerName=xyzsqlanywhereservername;
DatabaseName=report;',
CREDENTIAL = [PolyFriend] );
```

Host == machinename:port, the machinename where SQLAnywhere resides and port most likely the default 2638 where the SQLAnywhere service is listening for connections.

ServerName == the name of the SQLAnywhere server/service which hosts the database (connect to the SQLAnywhere db and execute select @@servername).

Comment: It was the @@servername that I was missing. THANK YOU ! I have been racking my head. 

do you know why I would be getting an 
Generic ODBC error: [SAP][ODBC Driver]Invalid use of null pointer .
when creating an external table: 
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE v_event(
event_id int NULL
) WITH (
LOCATION='xxx.jjj.v_event',
DATA_SOURCE=external_data_source_name2
);

I am just trying to create a table with one column for testing

Comment: just use LOCATION='dbo.v_event', no need for 3 part names , because the DatabaseName (or Database) has been specified in the connection_options.Also make sure that the exact same datatypes&nullability are used on both sides (event_id int null  for both sql external table and anywhere dbo.v_event )

Comment: I updated my progress and included what happens if I only put schema.table

Comment: in your edit, the location is set as LOCATION = 'sqlserver:..", shouldnt it be LOCATION = 'odbc://..."? Also the DBN connection property is outdated(?), just use DatabaseName (or Database) it works with both.

Comment: that might have been an issue.

Comment: I can now create external tables and query them if I do not use TOP 
the error I get is "Syntax error near 'limit' on line 3". this is because sybase doesnt accept limit 

I am using the same driver for a linked server and I can use the top 100 * server.db.schama.table